# Permanent notification error

Tags: android

I have big problem with permanent notification i cant add codes like `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` etc. What can i do? Here Is my code:

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(NoteActivity.this);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_assignment_late_black);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Alert!");
mBuilder.setContentText(notess);
mBuilder.setDefaults( Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(false);
notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Welcome! Are you getting an error? If so, what line? If not, can put put a line in that tries to add `FLAG_NO_CLEAR`, and show us what it does?

Comment: what are trying to achieve exactly? what is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `Notification.Builder` to set ongoing notifications

```
mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
```